# Regex for string that do not start with any character of a group and do not contain any of multiple substring

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-negation

This might be simple, but I have lost a ridiculous amount of hours trying to get there by myself. I need to have a regex that:

1. Do not start with '_' or '-'.
2. Do not end with '_' or '-'.
3. Do not contain '__' or '--' or '_-' or '-_'.

I spent hours on a [regex builder](https://regexr.com/) and I can't get there. I know I can find a way for each of those criteria separately but I can't have them together.

### Update

I forgot to mention it must also only contain these characters [a-zA-Z0-9_-].

Comment: Could you provide some test cases and your tries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
^(?![-_])(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]|[-_](?![-_]))+(?<![_-])$
```

See: [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/9ioSJs/latest)

---

Explanation

- `^` start of string from where...
- `(?![-_])` not a `-` or `_` is follwing
- `(?:` then a repetition of

  - `[a-zA-Z0-9]` a character that can come at any time
  - `|` or
  - `[-_]` a `-` or `_`
  - `(?![-_])` as long as its not followed by another `-` or `_`
- `)+`
- `(?<![_-])$` with the last letter also not beeing `-` or `_`

Answer (score 0):

We can use the following pattern:

```
^[^_-](?!.*(?:__|--|_-|-_))(?:.*[^_-])?$
```

This pattern says to match:

- `^` from the start of the input

  - `[^_-]` match any leading character OTHER than underscore or hyphen
  - `(?!.*(?:__|--|_-|-_))` assert that `__`, `--`, `_-`, or `-_` do not occur
  - `(?:.*[^_-])?` then match anything so long as it does not end in `_` or `-`
- `$` end of the input

### Demo

Comment: This works for the original question, but what if it also must only contain these characters [a-zA-Z0-9_-] ?

Comment: @cldtech Changing your question after others have answered is strongly frowned upon.

Comment: What do you want me to do, i tried to make a new question but it got closed in seconds. Just like every time i try to ask something on stackoverflow. This site is horribly managed, not my fault.

Comment: I agree that the site is mismanaged.  But the reason I posted the above comment is that if you change your question after others have answered then you _invalidate_ those other answers.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, here's a regex that should work.

```
^(?![_-]|.*[_-]{2}|.*[_-]$)
```

```
^                 # beginning of the string
(?!...|...|...)   # negative lookahead with OR conditions, neither of the following criterias should be matched
[_-]              # 1. starting with `_` or `-`
.*[_-]{2}         # 2. any consecutive `-` or `_` (`_-`, `-_`, `--` or `__`)
.*[_-]$           # 3. ending with `_` or `-`
```

See the [tests](https://regexr.com/7tpf3)

Answer (score 0):

You can match the strings you are interested in with this regex:

```
^[^_-](?:[^_-]|[_-][^_-])*$
```

This matches:

- `^` : beginning of string
- `[^_-]` : a character which is not an `_` or `-`
- `(?:[_-][^_-]|[^_-])*` : some number of **either**:

  - `[^_-]` : a character which is not an `_` or `-`; **or**
  - `[_-][^_-]` : an `_` or `-` which is followed by a character which is not an `_` or `-`;
- `$` : end of string

Note that the second part of the alternation requires a character to follow an `-` or `_`, this ensures the string cannot end with `-` or `_`.

This will be more efficient than using lookaheads.

Demo on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/uOXNv1/1)

Note that as pointed out by @HaoWu in the comments, the alternation can be simplified to an optional `_` or `-` followed by a character which is not an `_` or `-` i.e.

```
^[^_-](?:[_-]?[^\n_-])*$
```

This is slightly more efficient again.

Demo on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/k3An8p/1)

Comment: This is very clever +1.  But note that if requirements change the OP might be forced to revert using a lookahead.

Comment: [`^[^_-](?:[_-]?[^_-])*$`](https://regex101.com/r/k3An8p/1) should do the same

Comment: @HaoWu yes, that is a natural optimisation of the alternation I have. With your permission I'll edit the answer to use that instead

Comment: @Nick Yeah ofc, this is entirely your approach but simplified ;)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen agreed - this answer is specific to this exact question.

Comment: @cldtech You can deal with your character requirement with a simple change to this answer, replacing `[^_-]` with `[a-zA-Z0-9]`: [`^[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[_-]?[a-zA-Z0-9])*$`](https://regex101.com/r/k3An8p/2). This still doesn't use lookaheads and so is more efficient than the other solutions.